# How to solve ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis error?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am unable to find an error in this code, it shows ***ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis*** for both. I'm doing this on Oracle live SQL.

```
CREATE table Final_chart 
( 
T_id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Train(T_id), 
User_id varchar(10) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Passenger(User_id), 
Seat_id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Train_Seats(Seat_id), 
CONSTRAINT PNR PRIMARY KEY (T_id,User_id,Seat_id)  
)

CREATE table Train_seats  
(  
T_id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Train(T_id), 
Seat_id int PRIMARY KEY,  
Waiting int NOT NULL,  
Available int NOT NULL,  
Booked_seat int NOT NULL  
)
```

[image]

Comment: Really sorry for adding mysql tag, I'm using Oracle....

Comment: Try terminating each statement with a `;` So `CREATE table tablename (columns....);`

Comment: Igor, done with that too....doesn't work

Comment: Perhaps you need separate foreign key specifications, e.g. `constraint pass_fk FOREIGN KEY (User_id)  REFERENCES Passenger(User_id),`, instead of as a part of the column spec.

Comment: @jarlh, but I think you still need to have what column is part of the constraint as well... `constraint pass_fk FOREIGN KEY (User_Id) REFERENCES Passenger(User_id)`

Comment: @jarlh and WEI_DBA, im getting invalid identifer error ...

Answer (score 2):

Working example for one table. And please use varchar2 instead on varchar in oracle.

```
CREATE table Final_chart 
(T_id integer, 
User_id varchar2(10), 
Seat_id integer,
CONSTRAINT t2_fk  FOREIGN KEY (T_id) REFERENCES Train(T_id),
CONSTRAINT t1_fk  FOREIGN KEY (User_id) REFERENCES Passenger(User_id),
CONSTRAINT t3_fk FOREIGN KEY  (Seat_id) REFERENCES Train_Seats(Seat_id),
CONSTRAINT Pkr PRIMARY KEY (T_id, User_id, Seat_id)
)
```

Comment: and plus ONE on using VARCHAR2 over VARCHAR

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your reference to the foreign key. this is the way you should do it

```
CONSTRAINT FK_Train FOREIGN KEY (T_id) REFERENCES Train(T_id)
```

Comment: I had none. Make sure each reference follow the same pattern. CONSTRAINT Constraint_Name FOREIGN KEY (column) REFERENCES Table(Table_Column)